# Google Dataflow webhooks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, webhooks, dataflow

I'm trying to find a way to trigger 2 or 3 jobs in Dataflow and wait for the 3 of them to finish whatever they were suppose to do. And once the 3 of them are done they need to execute another process in a server.

Like a webhook automating a process, is that possible? And if it is possible how would be the way to do it?

I think it could be possible to use a Google Cloud Function to wait for a response of some sort from Dataflow as soon as a job finishes. However, I'm not sure if that is the best way to go.

Comment: I would look into Composer/Airflow for these workflows

Comment: @GuillemXercavins can you clarify a bit what would be your idea? I'm new to all this

Comment: Sure, [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org) is an open-source tool to orchestrate tasks (jobs) that constitute a DAG (workflow). It can be useful when you have dependencies between tasks, to handle task retries, monitor jobs, send mails on failures, etc. You can force that a downstream process is only executed when the three upstream jobs have succeeded with: `[job1, job2, job3] >> process` ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#bitshift-composition)). [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/?hl=en) is the managed GCP version.